# how can i relation two JSON files(one file include one array) by id?

Tags: javascript, node.js

- this are located in sepatatle in JSON files.
- first route excecute student.json
- second route excecute parent.json
- when excecute the first route all the details display in browser. but go to second route i want to display the details incluting in Student details also

### student.json

```
    "Students" : [
        {"ID" : "1" ,
         "Name" : "janaka",
         "Grade" : "A"
        },
        {"ID" : "2" ,
         "Name" : "Darshana",
         "Grade" : "B"
        },
```

### parent.json

```
"parents" : [
        {"pID" : "1" ,
         "pName" : "janaka ravindra"
        },
        {"pID" : "2" ,
         "pName" : "Darshana disanayaka"
        },
```

### this is first route

```
app.get('/students/:id',function(req ,res){

    console.log('got a get request from homepage');

    fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "Students_details.json", 'utf8',function(err,data){
     //convert data to json
     //Get content of the student array to new vareable
     //get requested id to new variable

     var student = studentsArray.find(st => { 
        return st.ID == studentId;

       res.send(student); // this give student object array
    });
}
```

### second route

```
app.get('/getFullStudentDetails/:id',function(req , res){
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "parent.json", 'utf8',function(err,data){

    // this array also convert to the jsone object
}
```

- first route give only {ID,Name,Grade]
- But in Second route want to give {pID,Name,Grade,Fullname} first route details also
- how can i relation this two using pId as a forigin key?
- how i pass the data first route to second am i want?

Comment: simple loop should do it

Comment: but how? can you give me a example according to the array details?

Comment: I do not see the logical connection of the two files. Is student.ID connected to parent.pID and student.Name to parent.pName? If so the ID is enough and there would be no actual parent data.

Comment: I'll write code when you show what you've tried

Comment: there is a two array. one array have [ID,name,grade] like this another array have [pID,fullName]. if i use pID as a forging key like this [ID,name,grade,pID]. if am i right how can i do that?

Comment: Yes but this links students to students (name to fullName by using ID and pID) and not students to parents. Which makes it a redundant 1:1 connection. Anyhow, appart from that, use a loop like Jaromanda X recommenced.

Comment: i updated my question! please look and help

Comment: Your source code has some errors. Can you please check that you copied your code correctly? Also, your '/students/:id' API should not return an array, it should return an object.

Comment: in retern using a jquary i have created a interface! it get using rhis in html file here is the code $.get(URL,function(responseText)

Comment: url = URL = `http://localhost:8081/students/${stId}`;  ${stId} this means var stId = document.getElementById('demonum').value;